# How to convert date picker value into String in swift 3.0?

Tags: date, datepicker, swift3, xcode8, nsdateformatter

How to convert date picker value into String type in Swift 3.0 ?

Right now I have managed to create date picker but the value that appear in textfield is today's date which is **2/8/17, m/d/yy** format.

My goal is to convert **m/d/yy** into **String** and the date value will be **2017-02-08, yyyy/mm/dd** format

The code as below.

**Date.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var dateTxt: UITextField!

    let datepicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayDate()
    }

    func displayDate(){
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePick))
        toolbar.setItems([doneBtn], animated: false)

        dateTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

        dateTxt.inputView = datepicker
    }

    func donePick(){

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

        dateTxt.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datepicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you need to set [`dateFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter/1413514-dateformat) property of `DateFormatter` not the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`.

```
func donePick(){

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateTxt.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datepicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: is it store automatically as string ? i mean that date "yyyy-MM-dd" value

Comment: Cause i want to post the value as string type into web server.

Comment: @Jamilah You want date in format "2017-02-08", so you need to set its according dateFormat with `DateFormatter` in your case it is `yyyy-MM-dd`, try like my answer will work in a way you want.